# Calling an API with string parametrs in Android with Volley

Tags: java, android, api, android-volley

I'am trying to call an API that adds data to a dynamoDB each time a user creates an account .
The url of the API is in the following format :

```
https://t3x9lg8utf.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod? id=""&username=""&numero_passeport=""&decision=""
```

The problem is that when i call the API using volley i get this error :

```
06-03 14:32:23.599 13503-14515/com.amazonaws.youruserpools.CognitoYourUserPoolsDemo E/Volley: [14796] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://t3x9lg8utf.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod
```

The code i used to call the API :

```
  StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://t3x9lg8utf.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.e("HttpClient", "success! response: " + response.toString());
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("HttpClient", "error: " + error.toString());
                        }
                    })
            {
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("id","\"\"");
                    params.put("username","\"zaeae\"");
                    params.put("numero_passeport","\"\"");
                    params.put("decision","\"\"");

                    return params;
                }
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(sr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://t3x9lg8utf.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod?id="+Uri.encode(id)+"&username="+Uri.encode(username)+"&numero_passeport="+Uri.encode(numero_passeport)+"&decision="+Uri.encode(decision),
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.e("HttpClient", "success! response: " + response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("HttpClient", "error: " + error.toString());
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("id","\"\"");
                params.put("username","\"zaeae\"");
                params.put("numero_passeport","\"\"");
                params.put("decision","\"\"");

                return params;
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(sr);
```

also pass values for `id, username, numero_passeport and decision`

Comment: Same problem , different error :), i think it's an encoding problem , because the parameters have to be in string format : ( "ID") 

__
06-03 15:46:07.976 21537-22495/com.amazonaws.youruserpools.CognitoYourUserPoolsDemo E/Volley: [16015] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 502 for https://t3x9lg8utf.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod?id="hhhh"&username="hhhh"&numero_passeport="vvh"&decision="En cours de traitement"

Answer (score 0):

> ? id=""&

These are URL parameters, which cannot be passed via `getParams()`

You need to append them to the string after `Request.Method.GET`

Comment: Thank you for the answer , What do you mean by append ? i tried adding them to the string url but i got the same problem